# A local array repeats inside a loop! C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

The `current_name` is a local `char` array inside the following loop. I declared it inside the loop so it changes every time I read a new line from a file. But, for some reason the previous data is not removed from the `current_name`! It prints old data out if it wasn't overridden by new characters from the next line.

ANY IDEAS?

```
  while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    file.getline(current_line, LINE);

    int i = 0;
    while (current_line[i] != ';') {
      current_name[i] = current_line[i];
      i++;
    }

    cout << current_name << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Nothing abnormal. Nothing in the standard states that a block local variable **has to** change value at each iteration. It's only that you **cannot assume** that it will keep its value.

Comment: Local variables are not initialized automatically, so accessing it before assigning it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: [why `while(!file.eof())` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @A.S.H What do you mean?

Comment: Why does it matter if the previous data is removed? You're overwriting it with the data from the current line. The problem is that you're not adding a null terminator.

Comment: It's like a new variable at each iteration. So as @Barmar said, if you read it before writing to it (within a new iteration), its data is *undefined*.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` instead of a `char` array? They are automatically initialized to an empty string.

Comment: Would you show what you are talking about by showing some code. I am not getting what you mean. And to answer your question, the previous data needs to be removed because I compare it later with another array to see if there is a match. (THIS IS A SIMPLIFIED SNIPPETS FROM MY ORIGINAL CODE)

Comment: @Barmar I am not accessing anything before assigning!! What are you talking about?!!

Comment: How did you determine that the old contents are repeating if you didn't access them?

Comment: @Mosedince You didn't initialize any of the arrays though. Also, it doesn't need to remove data, nowhere in the standard says that. And, as fellow commenters said, accessing uninitialized variables is undefined behavior - which means - anything can happen.

Comment: @Barmar I am printing the result each time at the end of the loop!! And the result shows previous data!

Comment: Dude look at your question, we were answering your question:  `But, for some reason the previous data is not removed from the current_name! It prints old data out if it wasn't overridden by new characters from the next line.`

Comment: If you're only assigning to elements up to `i=5`, but you print elements past that, then you're accessing elements that you didn't assign.

Comment: @A.S.H and that exactly what happened! How do you want me to ask?

Comment: @Mosedince take it easy :). You asked a question very well, and we found that it is nothing abnormal and we tried to explain why we dont find it abnormal. Good to know that your issue was solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not terminating `current_name` after filling it.  Add `current_name[i] = 0` after the inner loop just before your `cout`.  You're probably seeing this if you read `abcdef` then read `jkl` and probably get `jkldef` for output

---

**UPDATE**

You wanted to know if there is a better way.  There is--and we'll get to it.  But, coming from Java, your question and followup identified some larger issues that I believe you should be aware of.  Be careful what you wish for--you may actually get it [and *more*] :-).  All of the following is based on love ...

---

> **Attention All Java Programmers!  Welcome to "A Brave New World"!**

---

**Basic Concepts**

Before we even get to `C` the **language**, we need to talk about a few concepts first.

Computer Architecture:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set

Memory Layout of Computer Programs:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Differences between Memory Addresses/Pointers and Java References:
[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

---

> **Concepts Alien to Java Programmers**

The C language gives you direct access the underlying ***computer architecture***.  It will *not* do anything that you don't *explicitly* specify.  Herein, I'm mentioning `C` [for brevity] but what I'm really talking about is a combination of *the memory layout and the computer architecture*.

- If you read memory that you didn't initialize, you will see seemingly random data.
- If you allocate something from the heap, you must explicitly free it.  It doesn't magically get marked for deletion by a garbage collector when it "goes out of scope".
- There is *no* garbage collector in C
- C pointers are far more powerful that Java references.  You can add and subtract values to pointers.  You can subtract two pointers and use the difference as an index value.  You can loop through an array *without* using index variables--you just deference a pointer and increment the pointer.
- The data of automatic variables in Java are stored in the heap.  Each variable requires a separate heap allocation.  This is slow and time consuming.
- In C, the data of automatic variables in stored in the *stack frame*.  The stack frame is a contiguous area of *bytes*.  To allocate space for the stack frame, C simply subtracts the desired size from the stack pointer [hardware register].  The size of the stack frame is the sum of *all* variables within a given function's scope, regardless of whether they're declared inside a loop inside the function.
- Its initial value depends upon what previous function used that area for and what *byte* values it stored there.  Thus, if `main` calls function `fnca`, it will fill the stack with whatever data.  If then `main` calls `fncb` it will see fnca's values, which are semi-random as far as fncb is concerned.  Both fnca and fncb must initialize stack variables before they are used.
- Declaration of a C variable *without* an *initializer* clause does *not* initialize the variable.  For the bss area, it will be zero.  For a stack variable, you must do that explicitly.
- There is *no* range checking of array indexes in C [or pointers to arrays or array elements for that matter].  If you write beyond the defined area, you will write into whatever has been mapped/linked into the memory region next.  For example, if you have a memory area: `int x[10]; int y;` and you [inadvertently] write to `x[10]` [one beyond the end] you will corrupt `y`
- This is true regardless of which memory section (e.g. data, bss, heap, or stack) your array is in.
- C has *no* concept of a *string*.  When people talk about a "c string" what they're *really* talking about is a `char` array that has an "end of string" (aka EOS) *sentinel* character at the end of the useful data.  The "standard" EOS char is almost universally defined as 0x00 [since ~1970]
- The only *intrinsic* types supported by an architecture are: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`/`pointer`, `long long`, and `float/double`.  There may be some others on a given arch, but that's the usual list.  Everything else (e.g. a `class` or `struct` is "built up" by the compiler as a convenience to the programmer from the arch *intrinsic* types)

Here are some things that *are* about C [and C++]:
- C has *preprocessor* macros.  Java has no concept of macros.  Preprocessor macros can be thought of as a crude form of *metaprogramming*.
- C has `inline` functions.  They look just like regular functions, but the compiler will attempt to insert their code directly into any function that calls one.  This is handy if the function is cleanly defined but small (e.g. a few lines).  It saves the overhead of actually calling the function.

---

**Examples**

Here are several versions of your original program as an example:

```
// myfnc1 -- original
void
myfnc1(void)
{
    istream file;

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        char current_line[LINE];
        char current_name[NAME];

        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        int i = 0;

        while (current_line[i] != ';') {
            current_name[i] = current_line[i];
            i++;
        }

        current_name[i] = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc2 -- moved definitions to function scope
void
myfnc2(void)
{
    istream file;
    int i;
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        i = 0;

        while (current_line[i] != ';') {
            current_name[i] = current_line[i];
            i++;
        }

        current_name[i] = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc3 -- converted to for loop
void
myfnc(void)
{
    istream file;
    int i;
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        for (i = 0;  current_line[i] != ';';  ++i)
            current_name[i] = current_line[i];
        current_name[i] = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc4 -- converted to use pointers
void
myfnc4(void)
{
    istream file;
    const char *line;
    char *name;
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        name = current_name;
        for (line = current_line;  *line != ';';  ++line, ++name)
            *name = *line;
        *name = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc5 -- more efficient use of pointers
void
myfnc5(void)
{
    istream file;
    const char *line;
    char *name;
    int chr;
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        name = current_name;
        line = current_line;
        for (chr = *line++;  chr != ';';  chr = *line++, ++name)
            *name = chr;
        *name = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc6 -- fixes bug if line has no semicolon
void
myfnc6(void)
{
    istream file;
    const char *line;
    char *name;
    int chr;
    char current_line[LINE];
    char current_name[NAME];

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        name = current_name;
        line = current_line;
        for (chr = *line++;  chr != 0;  chr = *line++, ++name) {
            if (chr == ';')
                break;
            *name = chr;
        }
        *name = 0;

        cout << current_name << endl;
    }
}

// myfnc7 -- recoded to use "smart" string
void
myfnc7(void)
{
    istream file;
    const char *line;
    char *name;
    int chr;
    char current_line[LINE];
    xstr_t current_name;
    xstr_t *name;

    name = &current_name;
    xstrinit(name);

    while (isOpen && !file.eof()) {
        file.getline(current_line, LINE);

        xstragain(name);

        line = current_line;
        for (chr = *line++;  chr != 0;  chr = *line++) {
            if (chr == ';')
                break;
            xstraddchar(name,chr);
        }

        cout << xstrcstr(name) << endl;
    }

    xstrfree(name);
}
```

---

Here is a "smart" string [buffer] class similar to what you're used to:

```
// xstr -- "smart" string "class" for C

typedef struct {
    size_t xstr_maxlen;                 // maximum space in string buffer
    char *xstr_lhs;                     // pointer to start of string
    char *xstr_rhs;                     // pointer to start of string
} xstr_t;

// xstrinit -- reset string buffer
void
xstrinit(xstr_t *xstr)
{

    memset(xstr,0,sizeof(xstr));
}

// xstragain -- reset string buffer
void
xstragain(xstr_t xstr)
{

    xstr->xstr_rhs = xstr->xstr_lhs;
}

// xstrgrow -- grow string buffer
void
xstrgrow(xstr_t *xstr,size_t needlen)
{
    size_t curlen;
    size_t newlen;
    char *lhs;

    lhs = xstr->xstr_lhs;

    // get amount we're currently using
    curlen = xstr->xstr_rhs - lhs;

    // get amount we'll need after adding the whatever
    newlen = curlen + needlen + 1;

    // allocate more if we need it
    if ((newlen + 1) >= xstr->xstr_maxlen) {
        // allocate what we'll need plus a bit more so we're not called on
        // each add operation
        xstr->xstr_maxlen = newlen + 100;

        // get more memory
        lhs = realloc(lhs,xstr->xstr_maxlen);
        xstr->xstr_lhs = lhs;

        // adjust the append pointer
        xstr->xstr_rhs = lhs + curlen;
    }
}

// xstraddchar -- add character to string
void
xstraddchar(xstr_t *xstr,int chr)
{

    // get more space in string buffer if we need it
    xstrgrow(xstr,1);

    // add the character
    *xstr->xstr_rhs++ = chr;

    // maintain the sentinel/EOS as we go along
    *xstr->xstr_rhs = 0;
}

// xstraddstr -- add string to string
void
xstraddstr(xstr_t *xstr,const char *str)
{
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(str);

    // get more space in string buffer if we need it
    xstrgrow(xstr,len);

    // add the string
    memcpy(xstr->xstr_rhs,str,len);
    *xstr->xstr_rhs += len;

    // maintain the sentinel/EOS as we go along
    *xstr->xstr_rhs = 0;
}

// xstrcstr -- get the "c string" value
char *
xstrcstr(xstr_t *xstr,int chr)
{

    return xstr->xstr_lhs;
}

// xstrfree -- release string buffer data
void
xstrfree(xstr_t *xstr)
{
    char *lhs;

    lhs = xstr->xstr_lhs;
    if (lhs != NULL)
        free(lhs);

    xstrinit(xstr);
}
```

---

**Recommendations**

- Before you try to "get around" a "c string", embrace it.  You'll encounter it in many places.  It's unavoidable.
- Learn how to manipulate pointers as easily as index variables.  They're more flexible and [once you get the hang of them] easier to use.  I've seen code written by programmers who didn't learn this and their code is always more complex than it needs to be [and usually full of bugs that I've needed to fix].
- Good commenting is important in any language but, perhaps, more so in C than Java for certain things.
- Always compile with `-Wall` `-Werror` and fix *any* warnings.  You have been *warned* :-)
- I'd play around a bit with the `myfnc` examples I gave you.  This can help.
- Get a firm grasp of the basics before you ...

---

**And now, a word about C++ ...**

Most of the above was about architecture, memory layout, and C.  All of that *still* applies to C++.

C++ *does* do a more limited reclamation of stack variables when the function returns and they go out of scope.  This has its pluses and minuses.

C++ has many classes to alleviate the tedium of common functions/idioms/boilerplate.  It has the `std` standard template library.  It also has `boost`.  For example, `std::string` will probably do what you want.  But, compare it against my xstr first.

But, once again, I wish to caution you.  At your present level, work *from* the fundamentals, not *around* them.

Comment: Exactly! I am going to try that

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Would you explain how would I prevent that from happening in a better way (if there is)? BECAUSE, in Java the one I wrote should work just fine!

Comment: @Mosedince C-style arrays are weird. You could use C++ style arrays instead, or in this case, C++ strings.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `current_name[i] = 0`; as described did not work for me.
Also, I got an error on isOpen as shown in the question. 
Therefore, I freehanded a revised program beginning with the code presented in the question, and making adjustments until it worked properly given an input file having two rows of text in groups of three alpha characters that were delimited with " ; " without the quotes. That is, the delimiting code was space, semicolon, space. This code works.

Here is my code.

```
     #define LINE 1000

    int j = 0;
    while (!file1.eof()) {
        j++;
        if( j > 20){break;} // back up escape for testing, in the event of an endless loop

        char current_line[LINE];
        //string current_name = ""; // see redefinition below

        file1.getline(current_line, LINE, '\n');

        stringstream ss(current_line); // stringstream works better in this case

        while (!ss.eof()) {

            string current_name;
            ss >> current_name;
            if (current_name != ";")
            { 
                cout << current_name << endl;
            } // End if(current_name....

            } // End while (!ss.eof...

    } // End while(!file1.eof() ...

    file1.close();

    cout << "Done \n";
```

Comment: this repeats the `while...eof` mistake (twice)

Comment: Not a mistake.  note one is using eof on a file and the other is using elf on a string stream.  Search on that and you should see examples in StackOverflow. Be sure you are correct before marking something a mistake and then marking it down. Suggest you retract that -1.

Comment: No, it is a mistake. The existence of other posts with the same mistake doesn't make it a non-mistake.  [Read this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Not a mistake. Check the documentation on file streams vs string streams.  You'll get the same answer.  And don't overlook that fact that this works perfectly.  Remember, string stream vs. file stream.

Comment: `eof` is a member of `ios`, which is a base class to both of those streams . It is just as much a mistake on the `ifstream` as it is on the `sstream` .

Comment: No, and I don't intend to . Fix your code if you want downvotes retracted.

Comment: You have no credibility if you don't even try to test it. You saying it is a mistake doesn't make it a mistake.

Comment: Have you bothered to read the thread I linked where hundreds of people vote that it is a mistake?

Comment: Get back to me after you've tested it.

Comment: You're clearly new to C++. A program appearing to work correctly in one instance is no guarantee that the program is actually correct. Broken code will sometimes coincidentally produce the same output as correct code. I'll say no more here.    For "credibility" you could look at site reputation.

Comment: Like I said, get back to me after you have tested it.